# Cannot change MS Office 2010 icons

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office-2010

I'm trying to customize my desktop icons.
But I encountered a problem. The option for changing the icon in Word 2010 is grayed out. What am I supposed to do? I tried to change the folder ownership. But no good. I also tried using [Icon Changer](http://www.shelllabs.com/), but it's still showing up the same icon.

[image]

I want to replace the icon with something black and white like this one:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Microsoft does something weird with the shortcuts for Office applications (and others).  I don't know *why* they do this but I'm sure they have their reasons.  Anyway, the simplest way to get around this is to create your own shortcuts to the Office executable files.  On my Windows XP, Office 2007 box, those files are in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12: WINWORD.EXE, EXCEL.EXE and so on.  Right click > Send To > Desktop or one of the many other ways to create shortcuts should work.  Then you can customize all you want.